# Difference between `recipientId` vs. `recipientIdGuid`

Tags: docusignapi

While I was poking around the DocuSign API getting it set up for an application, I noticed recipients have two separate ID's, one being a `recipientId` and the other `recipientIdGuid`.

The first value `recipientId` appears to be plain numbers, whereas the other value looks to be a UUID or hash of some kind.

I'm assuming the `recipientId` fields are unique to the envelope, whereas the `recipientIdGuid` version is unique across the service?  I'm trying to get the Docusign Connect service set up currently, so I'm wondering what I should be storing locally in our own DB.

Comment: You are correct on your assumptions above. recipientId is unique to the envelope and recipientIdGuid is unique to the environment. If you're going to do anything on the connect side with recipient's, I'd recommend only focusing on recipientId as you're worried about envelope data only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- RecipientGUID is the GUID for a particular recipient on a particular envelope. No two recipients will ever have the same recipientGUID.
- RecipientId is a local reference integer, used for mapping recipient to other objects, such as mapping the recipient in the envelope to tabs assigned to them in that envelope. The Sender sets these values. No two recipients in the same envelope will have the same ID, but across envelopes there is no uniqueness requirement.